# Using Puppeteer to extract text from span

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to extract the text of a span by it's class name but I'm getting returned nothing. I don't know if its because the page isn't loading in time or not.

This is my current code:

```
async function Reload() {
    Page.reload()

    Price = await Page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName("text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render"))
    console.log(Price)
}
Reload()
```

HTML

```
<div class="icon-text-wrapper clearfix icon-robux-price-container">
     <span class="icon-robux-16x16 wait-for-i18n-format-render"></span>
     <span class="text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render">689</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer page.evaluate querySelectorAll return empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the function that you passed to `Page.evaluate()` returns a non-Serializable value.

from the [puppeteer official document](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.0.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

> If the function passed to the `page.evaluate` returns a **non-Serializable** value, then `page.evaluate` resolves to `undefined`

so you have to make the function that passed to `Page.evaluate()` returns the text of span element rather than returns the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object of span.

like the following code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const htmlCode = `
  <div class="icon-text-wrapper clearfix icon-robux-price-container">
     <span class="icon-robux-16x16 wait-for-i18n-format-render"></span>
     <span class="text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render">689</span>
  </div>
`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(htmlCode);

  const price = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render');
    return Array.from(elements).map(element => element.innerText); // as you see, now this function returns array of texts instead of Array of elements
  })

  console.log(price); // this will log the text of all elements that have the specific class above
  console.log(price[0]); // this will log the first element that have the specific class above

  // other actions...
  await browser.close();
})();
```

> NOTE: if you want to get the html code from another site by its url use [page.goto()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.0.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options) instead of `page.setContent()`

> NOTE: because you are using `document.getElementsByClassName()` the returned value of the function that passed to `page.evaluate()` in the code above will be array of texts and not text as `document.getElementById()` do

> NOTE: if you want to know **what is the difference between Serializable objects and non-serializable objects** read [the answers of this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687012/serializable-objects-vs-non-serializable-objects)